# Batch- How to replace variable in different file

Tags: file, variables, batch-file, replace

I'm trying use program A.bat to execute a command to replace a variable in program B.cmd from no to yes, so far the only thing i've been able to do is use

```
set variable=yes >>B.cmd
```

But that only adds a new variable and doesn't rid of the old one, is there a way to do this?

```
::B.cmd Says
set variable=no
::A.bat executes the command
set variable=yes >>B.cmd
::B.cmd now says
set variable=no
set variable=yes
```

Comment: I'd suggest you expand your question and tell us a little more about why you are doing this rather than attempting to focus on the microtask. The simplest method given what you've told us is `set variable=yes >B.cmd` - but that's not likely to solve the *actual* problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

Use FINDSTR to write everything but the unwanted line to a new file.
Append the new line
Move the output back to the original file name

```
>B.cmd.new (
  findstr /vxc:"set variable=no" B.cmd
  echo set variable=yes
)
move /y B.cmd.new B.cmd >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable in script A, then launch B within the same environment.

Or make AB-helper.cmd which contains just the line that sets the environment variable, and you can easily overwrite it without problem. B.cmd can `call AB-helper.cmd` instead of setting the variable.

Otherwise, you're looking at running a for loop over lines in the file, setting them as environment variables, then using expansion with replace and hoping you don't mash up anything else in the file. It would look like:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%l in (B.cmd) do (
    set myTMP=%%l
    if "!myTMP!"=="set variable=no" (
        echo set variable=yes >> B-new.cmd
    ) else (
        echo !myTMP! >> B-new.cmd
    )
)
ren B.cmd B-old.cmd
ren B-new.cmd B.cmd
```

Possible shorter way; `echo !myTMP:variable^=no=variable^=yes! >> B-new.cmd` instead of the `if/else` bit. I couldn't get the equals escaped properly to make the substitution work, though.